# Создание объекта через for и без

Tags: javascript

У меня есть вопрос про создание объекта через цикл и без него.
Когда я создаю объект через цикл у меня не возникает ошибок. Но когда я пытаюсь создать его без цикла то возникает ошибка: 
Identifier 'add_one ' has already been declared. Не подскажите почему так происходит?

```js
var AddHtml = function(){
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML+=arguments[0]
}

// Работает
for (let i=0;i<=2;i++) {
  let add_one = new AddHtml('1');
}

// Не работает
let add_one = new AddHtml('1');
let add_one = new AddHtml('1');
```

Comment: Дак Вам же пишет, что `add_one` уже зарезервирован, измените вторую переменную.

Comment: Вот буквально потому, что _«Identifier 'add_one ' has already been declared»_.

Answer (score 1):

> Identifier 'add_one ' has already been declared

`add_one` уже объявлена, Вам стоит лишь поменять имя второй переменной и всё будет работать.

```js
var AddHtml = function(){
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML+=arguments[0]
}

let add_one = new AddHtml('1');
let add_one2 = new AddHtml('2');
```

Comment: Я понял. Но почему тогда в цикле не происходит ошибок?

Comment: Было бы совсем замечательно, если бы Вы еще добавили объяснение, почему не возникает ошибок в цикле. :) Ну и в качестве бонуса, почему при замене `let` на `var` ошибка исчезает. :)